# firebase deploy gives a "path" error

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

After initiating my firebase app with

```
firebase init
```

I tried to deploy it with

```
firebase deploy
```

but I get this error

```
    === Deploying to 'fugis-auto-services-website'...

i  deploying database, storage, functions, hosting

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

So I looked at the firebase-debug.log and this is what it says

```
Tue May 01 2018 19:52:19 GMT-0500 (CDT)
[debug] [2018-05-02T00:52:19.967Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] 
[info] === Deploying to 'fugis-auto-services-website'...
[info] 
[info] i  deploying database, storage, functions, hosting
[debug] [2018-05-02T00:52:20.266Z] TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:39:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1157:7)
    at Config.path (/Users/vanessaflores/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/config.js:166:37)
    at /Users/vanessaflores/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/lifecycleHooks.js:68:38
    at _chain (/Users/vanessaflores/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:26:38)
    at /Users/vanessaflores/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:29:14
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:7)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What does your `firebase.json` look like?

Comment: Having the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Too late to answer but might help someone in future, I had the same issue, i added the public folder as mentioned by @Gleb and inside your firebase.json you need to specify the public folder as well, like so:

```
{
"hosting": {
"public": "public",
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "function": "helloWorld"
  }
]
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It seems the "public" argument is required for hosting to deploy. Note that you also must have an actual folder created, even though it can be empty.

Comment: any ideas why  get this error when deploying this: https://github.com/QuantumInformation/svelte-fullstack-starter/blob/master/firebase.json#L11 **The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)**

Comment: Seems to be true that we need public entry in the hosting object. If thats the case any way to only have cloud function rewrite alone?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by re-initializing firebase functions:

```
firebase init functions
```

You might want to first update your firebase-tools:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

and backup your existing functions directory.

Comment: didn't know init can be done separately for functions, firestore etc. `firebase init functions` ran the routine and fixed it for me

Answer (score 3):

Had same issue as i use hosting part just to setup headers, **public** property is necessary! If you not define it you would have this issue

Answer (score 0):

My problem ended up being that I updated my macOS to High Sierra 10.13.4 and that somehow screwed up my paths for nvm. I had to update nvm and I reinstalled Firebase and now things seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem so after debugging for 2 hours I solved the problem by downgrading npm-conf to 1.1.0 with the command `npm install npm-conf@1.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

I was using a firestore callback like onCreate or onUpdate without passing the actual document path.

```
functions.firestore
.document()
.onCreate()
```

Just turn it into

```
functions.firestore
.document('collection/doc')
.onCreate()
```